# Inaccurate Numbers on Popularity Trends?

Tags: sharepoint-server, popularity-trends

I recently viewed the Popularity trends data for our site, and while it appears to be tracking some usage numbers being captured, I question their accuracy.  Specifically, there are a few months where the values are zero, when I know that there were visitors to the site during those times.  Is there a setting that should be checked to address this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue may caused by disabled event receiver. Follow the troubleshooting steps in this article: [SharePoint 2016 Popularity Trends and Usage data return no results](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51478.sharepoint-2016-popularity-trends-and-usage-data-return-no-results.aspx). Enable event receivers using PowerShell if that is the issue.